# browser is not expanding as div width increases

Tags: css, html, width

I have a menu control within a div. Initially I set the div width as 100% and min-width as 1200px to make same as browser width. Number of items in menu may increase as per requirement in future. I just tested the browser behaviour by increasing the items in menu, here items at the end are going down. What I am expecting here is, browser should provide a horizontal bar when the div width increases, so all the items in menu will be displayed in one line.

CSS Code:

`.maindiv{
 position: relative;width: auto !important;width: 100%;min-width: 1200px;}`

my menu structure is

```
<div class="maindiv" >
   <ul><li></li></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the following CSS

```
.maindiv { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 1200px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I'm assuming you already have the list items displayed as inline or inline block...

```
.maindiv li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And my final advice is do you really want `min-width` - if people resize their browser below this then they will get a horizontal scrollbar on the browser window as well as the scroll bar on the div if their are more items than fit.